# How To Use Max function with group by using MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, max

I have those 3 tables

**candidates**

```
cdid   cdname   

1      Moussa
2      Moustafa
3      Haitham
```

**positions**

```
posid  posname   

1      pos1
2      pos2
3      pos3
```

**joboffers**

```
cdid    posid   salary
1        1       600
1        2       800
1        3       700
2        1       500
2        2       700
2        3       900
3        2       1000
3        3       500
```

I need to make a query that get the `cdname` with max salary for every position

the table should be like this

```
cdname         posname       salary

moussa          pos1          600
haitham         pos2          1000
moustafa        pos3          900
```

I am using this query but it's not getting the correct `cdid`

```
$sql="select joboffers.cdid,joboffers.posid,Max(joboffers.salary),candidates.cdname
            FROM joboffers,candidates
            Where joboffers.cdid=candidates.cdid 

            Group by joboffers.posid";
```

Comment: I think your desired output does not match with the requirement if you find max salary then moussa should have pos2 with 800 let me know if its correct.

Comment: No abhik , the output is correct, since am displaying for every position the candidate name that has the maximum salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
SELECT sub.cdname, sub.posname, sub.salary
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM joboffers jo
  INNER JOIN positions ps USING (posid)
  INNER JOIN candidates cd USING (cdid)
  ORDER BY posid, salary DESC
) sub
GROUP BY sub.posid
```

Comment: its a tricky way , i think there is another way , a technical way but this works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group by all non-aggregated columns, like this:

```
SELECT j.cdid, c.cdname, j.posid, MAX(j.salary)
FROM joboffers j
JOIN candidates c ON j.cdid = c.cdid
GROUP BY j.cdid, c.cdname, j.posid
```

Comment: No it should be just group by posname

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT c.cdname, p.posname, MAX(j.salary)
 FROM joboffers j
 INNER JOIN candidates c ON j.cdid = c.cdid
 INNER JOIN positions p ON j.posid = p.posid
 GROUP BY c.cdname, p.posname
```

Comment: i dont want to display all the data please read well the tables and what the last query should be

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`SELECT customerNumber, MAX(amount)
FROM payments
GROUP BY customerNumber
ORDER BY MAX(amount);